# Why does the python __slots__ not saving memory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, slots

```
class Player:
    # __slots__ = ['name','age','gsnum']
    def __init__(self,name,age,gsnum):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gsnum = gsnum
```

I defined this class, with three attributes

when using `__slots__` to save memory:

I get 36 for one instance (`sys.getsizeof()`)
if not using the `__slots__`,
I still get 36 as the memory size,

What's the problem here?
32bit Python 2.7

Comment: It looks like you commented out the slots declaration.

Comment: On my machine using `__slots__` for this example *increases* memory usage.

Comment: Is memory really a problem? Note that since python3.3 with the introduction of PEP 412 instances are able to share part of their `dict`s and thus the overhead for `dict`s per instance was significantly reduced.

Comment: @Bakuriu thanks, I didn't know that. Well, I just remembered this, I don't think it's a big deal either, but the results are the opposite

Answer (score 5):

The [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots) states that:

> The default can be overridden by defining `__slots__` **in a new-style class definition**. The `__slots__` declaration takes a sequence of instance variables and reserves just enough space in each instance to hold a value for each variable. Space is saved because `__dict__` is not created for each instance.

Emphasis mine.

Which means your class definition must look like:

```
class Player(object):
    __slots__ = ['name','age','gsnum']
    def __init__(self,name,age,gsnum):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gsnum = gsnum
```

You can tell if you've got it right if you try to assign a variable that does not exist in the slots definition. You'll get an `AttributeError`.

Incidentally with the new type class definition the class is `32 bytes` but with the slots its `36 bytes` on my system.

Comment: +1 -- Good catch. I didn't realize that the OP is using an outdated python version and forgot to inherit from `object`.  BTW: seems like `__slots__` decreases memory only with a single attribute.

Comment: why using object? you can test the size when using object, much bigger

Comment: @EricWang 'New Style' python class definitions must inherit from `object` unless using python 3, where they're new by default. `__slots__` will only work with new style classes as the docs state.

Comment: Ok. thanks. but why the opposite result?

Comment: @EricWang I may have mis-understood your question then, what is the problem you are having?

Comment: isn't the slots supposed to transfer the dict(object attributes) to tuple/list?that is for saving memory, but our results aren't obey the rule here. I forgot where, maybe david beazley demonstrated before, it sure save memory for one instance

Comment: @EricWang: `sys.getsizeof` is shallow. It doesn't report the memory occupied by objects that you might think of as "part of" the object if they're separate objects. For example, it doesn't count the size of the `__dict__` or anything the `__dict__` refers to.

Comment: @user2357112 yeah, I guess that's the problem here, is there other ways exist to check the size? maybe the original c file?

Comment: Note that using `sys.getsizeof` isn't the right choice. It will measure the size of the `PyObject` struct for the class. For regular object this does *not* include the `__dict__`. But when using `__slots__` the struct contains the fields so it will seem bigger, but overall memory footprint will be smaller. (@EricWang)